# How to fix the problems of 'MissingOutputException' about samtools_index

Tags: python, shell, bioinformatics, snakemake, qsub

I wrote the snakemake flow from fastp to gatk_bqsr,then i met this problem in the rule index_bqsr:

```
Submitted job 440 with external jobid 'Your job 870 ("snakejob.mpileup.440.sh") has been submitted'.
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in **line 179** of s01_prepare_analysis.py:
Missing files after 5 seconds:
gatk_bqsr/S54.bqsr.bam.bai
```

This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with `--latency-wait`.
I am correctly sure that the output and input in this rule(index_bqsr) is right,so what happened?

This is centos7 python3.5:

1. I rerun the flow nothing changed, then everything is ok.
2. I deleted the `gatk_bqsr/S54.bqsr.bam.bai`, then redid the flow, then got the same error.
3. I extracted the relevant code block, then tested. I cannot repeat the error.

```
164 rule gatk_bqsr2:
165     input:
166         "bwa/{sample}.rmdup.bam",
167         "gatk_bqsr/{sample}.recal.table"
168     output:
169         "gatk_bqsr/{sample}.bqsr.bam"
170     log:
171         "log/gatk_bqsr/{sample}.bqsr.log"
172     params:
173         "--java-options \"-Xmx15g -Djava.io.tmpdir=tmp\""
174     shell:
175         "{GATK} {params} ApplyBQSR "
176         "--bqsr-recal-file {input[1]} -R {REFERENCE} "
177         "-I {input[0]} -O {output} 1>{log} 2>&1"
178
179 rule index_bqsr:
180     input:
181         "gatk_bqsr/{sample}.bqsr.bam"
182     output:
183         "gatk_bqsr/{sample}.bqsr.bam.bai"
184     shell:
185         "{SAMtools} index {input}"
186
187 rule bedtools_rawbam:
188     input:
189         "bwa/{sample}.sort.bam",
190         "gatk_bqsr/{sample}.bqsr.bam.bai"
191     output:
192         "bedtools/{sample}.sort.bedgraph"
193     log:
194         "log/bedtools/{sample}.sort.bedgraph.log"
195     shell:
196         "{BEDtools} genomecov -ibam {input[0]} -bga > "
197         "{output} 1>{log} 2>&1"
```

1. The raw error message is:

```
[Mon Jun  3 21:13:43 2019]
rule index_bqsr:
    input: gatk_bqsr/S54.bqsr.bam
    output: gatk_bqsr/S54.bqsr.bam.bai
    jobid: 541
    wildcards: sample=S54*

*Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 179 of s01_prepare_analysis.py:
Missing files after 5 seconds:
gatk_bqsr/S54.bqsr.bam.bai
```

*This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider increasing the wait time with `--latency-wait`.*

2. I extracted the relevant code block, then tested and everything is ok. The test code is:

```
    SAMtools = "/home/my/anaconda2/bin/samtools"

    SAMPLE = ["S54",]

    rule all:
        input:
            expand("log/bedtools/{sample}.sort.bedgraph.log",sample=SAMPLE)

    rule gatk_bqsr2:
        input:
            "bwa/{sample}.rmdup.bam",
            "gatk_bqsr/{sample}.recal.table"
        output:
            "gatk_bqsr/{sample}.bqsr.bam"
        log:
            "log/gatk_bqsr/{sample}.bqsr.log"
        params:
            "--java-options \"-Xmx15g -Djava.io.tmpdir=tmp\""
        shell:
            "echo \"{GATK} {params} ApplyBQSR "
            "--bqsr-recal-file {input[1]} -R {REFERENCE} "
            "-I {input[0]} -O {output}\""

    rule index_bqsr:
        input:
            "gatk_bqsr/{sample}.bqsr.bam"
        output:
            "gatk_bqsr/{sample}.bqsr.bam.bai"
        shell:
            "{SAMtools} index {input}"

    rule bedtools_rawbam:
        input:
            "bwa/{sample}.sort.bam",
            "gatk_bqsr/{sample}.bqsr.bam.bai"
        output:
            "log/bedtools/{sample}.sort.bedgraph.log"
        log:
            "log/bedtools/{sample}.sort.bedgraph.log"
        shell:
            "echo \"bedtools genomecov -ibam {input[0]} -bga > "
            "{output}\" > {log}"
```

supplement DAG here:

[image]

Comment: the raw code is very long, while if need I can supply it.Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: My guess is that you are not using the `--latency-wait` parameter like specified in the error message. Can you show your snakemake command please?

Comment: nohup snakemake -s s01_prepare_analysis.py --rerun-incomplete --cluster "qsub -cwd -q all.q -l vf=10g,p=10" --jobs 5 1>run_snake.log 2>&1 &

Comment: Indeed you are using qsub so I suggest you use `--latency-wait 30`.

Comment: Could you please include the command it is trying to execute to generate the .bai file. You can get it with something like `snakemake -s s01_prepare_analysis.py -np --rerun-incomplete` (i.e., dry run (`-n`) with command printing (-p)).

Comment: @EricC. thanks for the reply. I tried --latency-wait 30, the first time it still report the same bug,while the second time everything was ok. but i do not know why. is it the bug of snakemake or my qsub env?

Comment: @merv the dry run result seems like that: `samtools index gatk_bqsr/S052.bqsr.bam`, that I am very sure it is ok, for when i run the flow not by qsub but in local computer node, everything is well.

Comment: It looks like my problem have not solved by the parameter `--latency-wait 30`, it happened again.

Comment: @Danielle maybe you should increase de latency. You probably have a very slow filesystem on the cluster you're using. On my cluster, the FS is beegfs and I use a `-latency-wait 100`. If you're sure everything is ok with your command, then it is worth waiting for 100 seconds to avoid the break of your snakemake.